# Dump first N documents of a collection with mongodump

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to MongoDB and I would like to know how to dump the first N elements of a collection with `mongodump`. I can't figure out the query I have to use.

And how would you dump the last N elements?

Answer (score 5):

There is no direct way to limit number of records to export via mongodump; however it is possible indirectly, using the [query parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-query).

First you need to find last(n) documents you need to export.

Let's say you want to export top 50 documents. First find 50th document _id – if you are finding first(n), then sort ascending order and use $lte operator down in query.

```js
db.col.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:-1}).skip(49).limit(1)
```

Note down the _id value.

Now pass your _id to mongodump and run it from console. (not from mongo shell)

```bash
mongodump \
--db <some_db> \
--collection <some_col> \
--query '{_id:{$gte:ObjectId("previously noted _id")}}'
```

Note: this solution exports the last(n) documents instead of first(n), but it is simple to adapt it.

Comment: mongoexport now supports --skip(), --limit(), --sort(), which makes this a lot easier.